# {exp:store:checkout} has stopped working

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

The {exp:store:checkout} tag has stopped working.

---

**What it does**

When you proceed to the next step, or otherwise "Submit" the checkout tag it reloads the page and goes back to the beginning

---

**What it should do**

Go to the next stage or payment provider (depending on step)

---

**Diagnosis Made**

Thinking it may be our template, we looked at the example store sample templates included. The same problem is occurring there.

This site did, until recently work and no changes were as far as I can see made. There has been no sales in a week.

---

**Software**

We are running EE 2.5.2 with Store 1.5.3. We tried to upgrade to 1.6.2 but the following errors occurred. Could they be related? http://pastebin.com/JqTLdTX6

Answer (score 1):

**This has been resolved**

We had the following in our .htaccess file.

```
## ENSURE THAT THERE IS ALWAYS A TRAILING SLASH ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

This messed up how forms submitted.

Sorry for the inconvinience.

(For what it's worth, the PHP errors persist).

Comment: For others who find this on Google, @AdrianMacneil's suggestion may be the valid fix but in our instance it didn't and was the .htaccess issue described above.